# How do I conditionally call an alert() in JavaScript based on conditions from my Java code?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, alert

I am trying to display an alert (a "Congratulations!" message) if data is recorded (through a form on the web page) that meets or exceeds a set Goal (that has already been recorded and stored); I was also considering maybe conditionally playing a cute little sound to go with it, but I would like to get the pop-up working first of course. I am pretty novice with JavaScript, so I hope this issue isn't a stupid oversight on my part. I did do some digging online and couldn't quite find a solution to fit exactly what I am trying to do here.

So, in my Java code I check if the data being recorded meets or exceeds the goal, and if it does then a boolean variable in the Goal object is set to true (to reflect that the Goal was completed). That boolean variable is being updated correctly. However, in my web page I cannot get the alert to pop up when wrapped in the conditions I have it in.

I know for a fact that the line of Java code below is being seen because I put a print statement before and after it, and both are printing.

Here is the related Java code:

```
model.addAttribute("goalMet", true);
```

And here is the related HTML and JS (I am using Thymeleaf):

```
<div th:if="${goalMet}">
<p> abc123 </p>
<script th:inline="javascript">
    function congratulate() {
      alert("Congratulations on achieving your Goal!");
    }
    congratulate()
</script>
</div>
```

The abc123 was just thrown in there for debugging, and it currently does not show up after recording data that meets a goal. I have tried a few variations of the script tag, both with and without the th:inline="javascript" part. I also tried moving the function definition into the html head tags and just  calling congratulate() in this conditional block. All of my attempts so far have been unsuccessful.

The only effects I am seeing after recording data that meets a goal is that the URL gets "?goalMet=true" appended to it.

Comment: What happens if you replace `"${goalMet}"` with `"${true}"` ?

Comment: The alert pops up as soon as I navigate to the page, and the "abc123" appears on the page.

Comment: In that case I imagine you realize the issue has to do with your Java class member and its use by Thymeleaf. Thymeleaf is interpreting whatever is stored in `goalMet` as false.

Comment: "_Goal object is set to true (to reflect that the Goal was completed). That boolean variable is being updated correctly._" <--- let's see this code please.

Comment: I have added the code you requested to the OP; I hope that helps. My understanding with using "model.addAttribute("name", value)" is that I can just give it a specified value (via the second parameter) and a name to reference it in an html file; is this correct? The "goalMet" is not intended to be linked to anything else.
Also, I added in my thoughts about what I currently think may be causing the issue at the bottom of the OP.

Comment: You are redirecting but not including `goalMet`. You might be better off using Redirect Attributes.

Comment: I tried adding "RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs" as a parameter to the logStrengthProgress() method shown above.
I then replaced "model.addAttribute("goalMet", true);" with "redirectAttrs.addAttribute("goalMet", true);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Randy Casburn's suggestions, I was able to get this working using Redirect Attributes. Here is what I did:

Changed

```
model.addAttribute("goalMet", true);
```

To

```
redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("goalMet", true);
```

And I added

"RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs" as a parameter to the method that does the redirect.